# What does +Counter do in python?

Tags: python

If `c = collections.Counter` then [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) show an expression `+c` that has the effect "remove zero and negative counts."  I haven't seen any such expression before in python.  Why does the expression have that effect?  What does it expand to?

**ETA:** Digging into the class I see that there is also a `-c` or `Counter.__neg__` operator that "*Subtracts from an empty counter.  Strips positive and zero counts, and flips the sign on negative counts.*"

These operator methods seem convenient but not intuitive.  Are there any precedents for using the unary operator in this way?

Comment: Neat find. I had no idea that you could do that.

Comment: Keep reading, _"Unary addition and subtraction are shortcuts for adding an empty counter or subtracting from an empty counter."_

Comment: FWIW, it expands to `Counter.__pos__(c)`

Comment: This is because `Counter` "overloads" the `__pos__` double-underscore (dunder) method by defining it itself.

Comment: Incidentally, I'm not aware of any other type that does anything interesting this operator. (I'm not sure any of the other examples in the linked duplicate are even *good*, let alone interesting.)